# ImportError - PYTHONPATH with same subfolders

Tags: python, import, importerror

I have 2 folders in my PYTHONPATH.

Both folders have the subfolder "tests".

When trying to import from the 2nd "tests" subfolder, I get ImportError.

How can this be resolved?

```
PYTHONPATH = /dir1:/dir2

ll /dir1
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 tests

ll /dir1/tests
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 0    __init__.py

ll /dir2
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 tests

ll /dir2/tests
-rw-rw-r--  3 me me 4096 myTest
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 0    __init__.py
```

When trying to import myTest:

```
import tests.myTest
```

I get ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tmp.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tests.myTest
ImportError: No module named myTest
```

Comment: Your definition of `PYTHONPATH` has spaces. I don't know what your shell is, but usually, they requires no spaces around the equal sign.

Comment: You can check for the module loading path on the Python prompt: `>>> import sys` followed by `>>> sys.path`. See if the resulting list contains your directories.

Comment: You have two packages called `tests` on Python's loading path (one with, and one without a `myTest` module). Which one should Python import? There is no way for Python to figure that out. Packages should have unique names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you list *dir1* before *dir2*.

PYTHONPATH becomes part of `sys.path`. When importing Python tries the directories in `sys.path` **in the order they are given** until it finds a package/module with a matching name.

In your example that means Python first looks into *dir1*, finds and imports the *tests* package from there and then tries to import *myTest* from that package – which fails.

You can solve this in three ways:

1. Change the order of directories in PYTHONPATH. That’s not a real good solution because instead of being unable to import *dir2/tests* you are now unable to import *dir1/tests*.
2. Rename the *tests* packages so they have unique names.
3. If *dir1* and *dir2* have the same parent directory, you could add that parent to PYTHONPATH and then import *myTest* as `dir1.tests.myTest`.

Comment: You are saying that  there's no way for better path resolution? Only renaming one of the folders?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m saying. Though I wouldn’t call a more sophisticated path resolution “better”. In my opinion it would be an awful mess if Python tried to be any cleverer. Maybe you’d want to add some more details to your question about what you’re trying to achieve. This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).